# Micronaut Annotation Processor for test-compile Eclipse+Maven does not working

Tags: eclipse-jdt, annotation-processing, micronaut

I am try to run a test with micronaut and jwt security. But the classes started with **$**, like **$$AnnotationMetadata.class** is not generated.

`micronaut 1.2.6`, `micronaut-test 1.1.2`, `jdk 1.8`, `eclipse 2019-09`

```java
    @MicronautTest
    public class JwtAuthenticationTest {
      @Inject
      EmbeddedServer embeddedServer;

      @Inject
      @Client("/")
      RxHttpClient   client;

      @Test
      public void whenVerifyJWTAuthenticationWorks() throws ParseException {
        //when: 'Accessing a secured URL without authenticating'
        HttpClientResponseException thrown = assertThrows(HttpClientResponseException.class, () -> {
            client.toBlocking().exchange(HttpRequest.GET("/user"));
        });
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, (thrown.getResponse().getStatus()));

      }
    }
```

## dir output of compiled class in target folders

```
 user\target\classes\com\acme\resources
 $HomeControllerDefinition$$exec1$$AnnotationMetadata.class
 $HomeControllerDefinition$$exec1.class
 $HomeControllerDefinition.class
 $HomeControllerDefinitionClass$$AnnotationMetadata.class
 $HomeControllerDefinitionClass.class
 $UserControllerDefinition$$exec1$$AnnotationMetadata.class
 $UserControllerDefinition$$exec1.class
 $UserControllerDefinition.class
 $UserControllerDefinitionClass$$AnnotationMetadata.class
 $UserControllerDefinitionClass.class
 HomeController.class
 UserController.class
```

## dir output of compiled class from test target folders

```
 user\target\test-classes\me\acme\user\resources
 JwtAuthenticationTest.class
```

But the eclipse/maven doesn't generate the annotation classes `$$AnnotationMetadata.class` from **Annotation Processor** for `testCompile` goal

My build element:

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                      <mainClass>${exec.mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                  </transformers>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <executable>java</executable>
              <arguments>
                <argument>-classpath</argument>
                <classpath/>
                <argument>-noverify</argument>
                <argument>-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1</argument>
                <argument>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote</argument>
                <argument>${exec.mainClass}</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
              <configuration>
                <detail>true</detail>
                <includes>
                  <include>%regex[.*]</include>
                </includes>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.7.0</version>
              <configuration>
                <compilerArgs>
                  <arg>-parameters</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                  <path>
                    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                    <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                  </path>
                  <path>
                    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                    <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                    <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                  </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
              </configuration>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>test-compile</id>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                      <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                      <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                      </path>
                      <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                      </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

**Eclipse log error for BeanDefinitionInjectProcessor**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.13.0.I20190916-1045
java.version=1.8.0_131
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core
Error
Thu Jan 30 19:43:47 GMT-03:00 2020
Exception thrown by Java annotation processor io.micronaut.annotation.processing.BeanDefinitionInjectProcessor@5cafe170

java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.handleProcessor(RoundDispatcher.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.round(RoundDispatcher.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.apt.pluggable.core.dispatch.IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processAnnotations(Compiler.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.GlobalBuildAction$1.run(GlobalBuildAction.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathMultiDirectory.directoryList(ClasspathMultiDirectory.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathDirectory.doesFileExist(ClasspathDirectory.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathDirectory.findClass(ClasspathDirectory.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathLocation.findClass(ClasspathLocation.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.findClass(NameEnvironment.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.findType(NameEnvironment.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.IModuleAwareNameEnvironment.findType(IModuleAwareNameEnvironment.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getType(LookupEnvironment.java:1701)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getResolvedType(LookupEnvironment.java:1631)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getResolvedJavaBaseType(LookupEnvironment.java:1643)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.AnnotationBinding.buildTargetAnnotation(AnnotationBinding.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.AnnotationBinding.addStandardAnnotations(AnnotationBinding.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.retrieveAnnotations(BinaryTypeBinding.java:1687)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding.getAnnotations(ReferenceBinding.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model.TypeElementImpl.getAnnotationBindings(TypeElementImpl.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model.ElementImpl.getPackedAnnotationBindings(ElementImpl.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model.ElementImpl.getAnnotationMirrors(ElementImpl.java:81)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.getRepeatableNameForType(JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:103)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.getRepeatableName(JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:97)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.getRepeatableName(JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:49)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.buildInternal(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:765)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.buildDeclared(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:111)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.validateAnnotationValue(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:336)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.readAnnotationRawValues(JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:248)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.readAnnotationRawValues(JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:49)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.processAnnotationDefaults(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:658)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.processAnnotationDefaults(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:647)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.populateAnnotationData(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:508)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.buildInternal(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:763)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.build(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:154)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.build(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:135)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.AnnotationUtils.getAnnotationMetadata(AnnotationUtils.java:194)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.AnnotationUtils.hasStereotype(AnnotationUtils.java:176)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.AnnotationUtils.hasStereotype(AnnotationUtils.java:159)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.BeanDefinitionInjectProcessor.lambda$process$2(BeanDefinitionInjectProcessor.java:136)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.BeanDefinitionInjectProcessor.process(BeanDefinitionInjectProcessor.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.handleProcessor(RoundDispatcher.java:142)
    ... 25 more
```

**Eclipse log error for TypeElementVisitorProcessor**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.13.0.I20190916-1045
java.version=1.8.0_131
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core
Error
Thu Jan 30 19:43:47 GMT-03:00 2020
Exception thrown by Java annotation processor io.micronaut.annotation.processing.TypeElementVisitorProcessor@77a28b3b

java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.handleProcessor(RoundDispatcher.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.round(RoundDispatcher.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.apt.pluggable.core.dispatch.IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processAnnotations(Compiler.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.GlobalBuildAction$1.run(GlobalBuildAction.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathMultiDirectory.directoryList(ClasspathMultiDirectory.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathDirectory.doesFileExist(ClasspathDirectory.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathDirectory.findClass(ClasspathDirectory.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathLocation.findClass(ClasspathLocation.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.findClass(NameEnvironment.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.findType(NameEnvironment.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.IModuleAwareNameEnvironment.findType(IModuleAwareNameEnvironment.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getType(LookupEnvironment.java:1701)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getResolvedType(LookupEnvironment.java:1631)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getResolvedJavaBaseType(LookupEnvironment.java:1643)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.AnnotationBinding.buildTargetAnnotation(AnnotationBinding.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.AnnotationBinding.addStandardAnnotations(AnnotationBinding.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.retrieveAnnotations(BinaryTypeBinding.java:1687)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding.getAnnotations(ReferenceBinding.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model.TypeElementImpl.getAnnotationBindings(TypeElementImpl.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model.ElementImpl.getPackedAnnotationBindings(ElementImpl.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model.ElementImpl.getAnnotationMirrors(ElementImpl.java:81)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.getRepeatableNameForType(JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:103)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.getRepeatableName(JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:97)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.getRepeatableName(JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:49)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.buildInternal(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:765)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.buildDeclared(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:111)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.validateAnnotationValue(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:336)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.readAnnotationRawValues(JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:248)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.readAnnotationRawValues(JavaAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:49)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.processAnnotationDefaults(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:658)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.processAnnotationDefaults(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:647)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.populateAnnotationData(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:508)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.buildStereotypeHierarchy(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:855)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.processAnnotationStereotypes(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:893)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.processAnnotationStereotype(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:886)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.buildInternal(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:827)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.build(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:154)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.build(AbstractAnnotationMetadataBuilder.java:135)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.AnnotationUtils.getAnnotationMetadata(AnnotationUtils.java:194)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.visitor.LoadedVisitor.matches(LoadedVisitor.java:100)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.TypeElementVisitorProcessor.lambda$null$1(TypeElementVisitorProcessor.java:104)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.TypeElementVisitorProcessor.lambda$process$2(TypeElementVisitorProcessor.java:104)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.TypeElementVisitorProcessor.process(TypeElementVisitorProcessor.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.handleProcessor(RoundDispatcher.java:142)
    ... 25 more
```

I have another project similar with this pom.xml thats works. And this sometimes the annotation processor works and sometimes not! Is There some trick?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: There is a bug for **Eclipse+Annotation Processor+Maven**, so I always run the maven command do compile: `mvn clean test-compile`, this way I have sure that classes will be generated.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks! We ended up solving our problem by upgrading to Gradle version 6.5.1.

Comment: Good to know too... I thought to change to gradle but I had a lot of work to move. Thanks.